# Nginx Proxy Manager: Connection refused when forwarding to Docker container of same Docker network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

Connections over my reverse proxy manager (Nginx Proxy Manager) to a docker container of the same docker network are refused. I just can't figure out why the connections are refused. I feel like the fix is simple. I hope you can help me out.

Here is my log and setup:

**when trying to access:** (on both http and https)

[image: grafik]

**from the error log:**

```
2020/10/08 18:03:02 [error] 269#269: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: ***.duckdns.org, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.3:80/", host: "***.duckdns.org"
2020/10/08 18:03:03 [error] 269#269: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: ***.duckdns.org, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.19.0.3:80/", host: "***.duckdns.org"
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.7"

services: 
  jetty:
    container_name: jetty
    image: jetty:9
    ports:
      - '80'
    volumes:
      - './jetty/webapps:/var/lib/jetty/webapps'
  # for reverse proxy
  nginx-pm:
    container_name: nginx-pm
    image: jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:2
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 80:80 # Public HTTP Port
    - 443:443 # Public HTTPS Port:
    - 81:81 # Admin Web Port:
    volumes:
    - ./nginx-proxy-manager/config.json:/app/config/production.json
    - ./nginx-proxy-manager/data:/data
    - ./nginx-proxy-manager/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
```

**proxy host setting:**

[image: grafik]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as initially suspected... the fix is really simple, but it cost me a few days -.- I just assumed the wrong (default) port for my jetty container since jetty's default port is 8080 but I was using 80 instead. As a result, I had to adapt the proxy host setting accordingly as well.

```
  jetty:
    container_name: jetty
    image: jetty:9
    ports:
      - '8080' # <---
```

Comment: and if it stayed in a separate composer how would it look?